# Ajax Request to AWS API Gateway can not parse json response

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am testing the code here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_get

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var processJSON =  function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
       alert(xhr.status);
    }
// for whatever reason, the following URL is not working any more, so you won't be able to test it anymore.
  var myURL='https://ckeqt3eoea.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pettest/test?name=223';
//  var myURL="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"

    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: myURL,
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: 'application/json',
          success: processJSON
        });


    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send Request</button>

</body>
</html>
```

As indicated in the code, I am trying to parse the response from this URL:
https://ckeqt3eoea.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pettest/test?name=223

And you can go to that URL directly and find out that the response from the `AWS-API-Gateway` is simply:

```
{
 "cc":"dd",
 "name":"ee"
}
```

I was able to use the above javascript to parse other `json` responses from other sources. But I am pulling my hair trying to parse the above response from `AWS-API-Gateway`.
if you uncomment the second line of `var myURL`, you will see that the code just really works for other URLs.

==========

In response to existing answers:

- I tried both `json` and `jsonp`. Both worked for other URLs (including the one I commented). But neither works for the AWS Gateway API.
- I also updated the code to use a named function. But again, it works for other URLs, but not for the AWS URL.
- I tested it on Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Your API probably isn't currently configured to support CORS, this would explain why hitting the URL directly will print JSON to the browser, but making a request from another client application to the server will reject your request meaning you get nothing back in your Data object. in AWS make sure you set the API to accepts CORS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the data type. You are telling jQuery to expect jsonp callback. What you are looking for is dataType: "json".

---

UPDATE

I just tested your code. Issue is that you don't have an OPTIONS method defined in your pettest/test resource. Using the API Gateway console, open the test resource (assume pettest is the stage and test is the resource), then use the "Actions" dropdown button to Enable CORS. This will automatically create the OPTIONS method and setup the required headers in your GET method.

Comment: I tried both `jsonp` and `json`. Both works for any other URLs I tried. But neither works for the AWS gateway API response.

Comment: I just tested your code. Issue is that you don't have an OPTIONS method defined in your pettest/test resource. Using the API Gateway console, open the test resource (assume pettest is the stage and test is the resource), then use the "Actions" dropdown button to Enable CORS. This will automatically create the OPTIONS method and setup the required headers in your GET method.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. Could you add the above response into the original answer? I would like to choose that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with your API. Probably doesn't matter, but instead of using 'resp' as the variable label, I used 'data'.

Also, calling a named function rather than embedding the function inline

```
    function processJSON(data) {
      alert(data.name);
    }

          dataType: "json",
          contentType: 'application/json',
```

Comment: It is still not working for me. Again, your modification and my original code work for any other URLs I tried but the AWS URL. (One of the other URLs is commented  in the above code example `// var myURL`)

Comment: I called your URL. When you hit the URL from a browser are you getting the expected JSON back? Try this: `alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));`